# How to avoid copying vendor proto dependencies on buf generate

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-gateway

I am testing grpc-gateway and trying to figure out the best way to import dependencies in my grpc service. I have the following dir structure:

```
proto/
  api.proto
  api2.proto
third_party/
  googleapis/
    google/
      api/
        http.proto
        annotations.proto
buf.yaml
buf.gen.yaml
```

buf.yaml config

```
version: v1beta1
build:
  roots:
    - third_party/googleapis
    - third_party/grpc-gateway
    - proto
```

Two things

- As you noticed I am using [buf.build](https://buf.build/) to generate proto files (you can ignore this fact if you know a better way);
- I am not copying `googleapi` under proto files intentionally and would like to keep them separate somewhere. I know google recommends keeping everything under `proto` folder and just copying dependent files (like `google/api/annotations.proto`), but I am not a fan of copying dozens of dependencies into my source code if I can avoid that somehow.

My question is, whenever I run `buf generate --path=./proto` (please notice path is set as a directory),  I get `googleapis` `pb.go` files copied under `proto/googleapis/` folder. I find it very annoying and cannot figure out what is wrong with my setup. If I specify every file directly, everything is fine (e.g. `buf generate --path=./proto/api.proto`), no third-party content is copied.

Is there a way to ignore `third_party` folders on `buf generate` and if not is there a better way to manage grpc dependencies. Copying files into every grpc project directly does make any sense for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured that out.
Usually, you'll be either reusing protos from your `go/src` folder (which has it's downsides due to repo updates) or you copy them into proto/dependency-x folder.

I find buf to take a bit better approach here, but you have to follow proto structuring guidelines which in short are: `structure proto files under same root, in different packets`. So, in order to avoid copying I have to have the following structure:

```
proto/
  api/ <- add one more level
    api.proto
    api2.proto
third_party/
  googleapis/
    google/
      api/
        http.proto
        annotations.proto
buf.yaml
buf.gen.yaml
```

and point buffer right into `api` folder like this: `buf generate --path=./proto/api`